# net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED error mysteriously disappears with axios post request

Tags: axios

I was attempting to make a post request with FormData to my local server using axios inside React. Here is the method that was posting to the server:

```
uploadHandler = () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append(
        "myFile",
        this.state.selectedFile,
        this.state.selectedFile.name
    );
    axios({
        method: "post",
        url: "/",
        data: formData
    }).then(response => {
    });
};
```

For the last three hours, I kept getting this error in my chrome console: 
`net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED` when firing the method. I could not figure out what was wrong and tried adding various headers to the request, but nothing worked.

Then, all of a sudden, it just WORKED. I had no idea why and hit ctrl z until I could pinpoint the exact change that got it to work. The hunt turned up nothing and now I can't get the error no matter how hard I try. This is driving me crazy not knowing what the issue was that took 3 hours of my day!

Has anyone experienced something similar? Am I missing something here? Any input is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have the same issue here. It's randomly occurring, which drives me crazy!

Comment: If you ever figure out why this is occurring, please let me know and I will do the same.

Comment: It was an issue related to Windows authentication (as we changed from HTTP to HTTPS). solved by some reverse proxy tweaks.